# update window gui problem

Tags: updates, gui

I have problem with updater window. when i want to download the updates through updater, it shows only one line such that I should scroll the text window to see which parts are going to update.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Can you post a screenshot of the problem?  Any more information as well, such as if this has always been an issue, or if it has worked before?

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it's a 16.10 bug.